# Проблема при запуске приложения в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, app

Проблема заключается в том, что при нажатии кнопки run приложение на телефон не устанавливается. Проект строится но не запускается. А во вкладке run появляется только одна строчка: 
09/02 20:04:44: Launching 'MainActivity' on samsung SM-J105H.
После этого ничего не происходит. 
У кого нибудь есть идеи как исправить это? Проблема возникла после последнего обновления до 3.5.

UPDATE

вот далеко не весь спиок ошибок из логов:

```
09-04 20:32:02.332 12192-12192/? E/Launcher.Model: onPackageChanged :ru.yandex.searchplugin
09-04 20:32:03.424 769-793/? E/GpsLocationProvider: sExerciseInterface is not available
09-04 20:32:03.724 31502-31515/? E/SQLiteLog: (283) recovered 284 frames from WAL file /data/user/0/com.google.android.gsf/databases/googlesettings.db-wal
09-04 20:32:04.144 31577-31577/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
09-04 20:32:04.144 31577-31577/? E/Zygote: v2
09-04 20:32:04.154 31577-31577/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-04 20:32:05.886 769-777/? E/asset: !@+++ closed '/mnt/asec/com.skype.raider-3/base.apk' by system_server(FinalizerDaemon)
09-04 20:32:07.277 31521-31617/? E/ReflectionUtils: getMethod() - An Exception(or error) occurred, name : isMultiSoundOn, message : java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: isMultiSoundOn []
09-04 20:32:07.277 31521-31617/? E/ReflectionUtils: getMethod() - An Exception(or error) occurred, name : getStreamVolume, message : java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getStreamVolume [int, int]
09-04 20:32:07.277 31521-31617/? E/ReflectionUtils: getMethod() - An Exception(or error) occurred, name : semGetPinDevice, message : java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: semGetPinDevice []
09-04 20:32:07.828 160-160/? E/batterysrv: file: /sys/class/power_supply/battery/hw_switch_point open error
09-04 20:32:07.978 31635-31635/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
09-04 20:32:07.978 31635-31635/? E/Zygote: v2
09-04 20:32:07.988 31635-31635/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: platform sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-04 20:32:08.428 31663-31663/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
09-04 20:32:08.428 31663-31663/? E/Zygote: v2
09-04 20:32:08.428 31663-31663/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: platform sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-04 20:32:08.829 916-3426/? E/KeyguardViewMediator: resetStateLocked
09-04 20:32:08.939 916-916/? E/LSO: LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
09-04 20:32:08.969 769-830/? E/MotionRecognitionService:  handler : SCREEN_OFF end 
09-04 20:32:09.039 769-853/? E/WifiNative-wlan0: do suspend true
09-04 20:32:09.079 31680-31680/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
09-04 20:32:09.079 31680-31680/? E/Zygote: v2
09-04 20:32:09.089 31680-31680/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: platform sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-04 20:32:09.099 769-793/? E/GpsLocationProvider: sExerciseInterface is not available
09-04 20:32:09.279 769-804/? E/PowerManagerService: handleSandman : startDreaming, but isDreaming false
09-04 20:32:09.309 157-157/? E/BufferQueueCore: [ColorFade] setDefaultMaxBufferCount: setting count to 3, previous is 2 
09-04 20:32:09.700 769-855/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=630, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
09-04 20:32:09.750 31696-31696/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
09-04 20:32:09.750 31696-31696/? E/Zygote: v2
09-04 20:32:09.760 31696-31696/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-04 20:32:09.820 769-31711/? E/MISC PowerHAL: sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/event2/device/enabled: No such file or directory
09-04 20:32:09.910 1633-1642/? E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException
        at android.os.Parcel.writeException(Parcel.java:1446)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:452)
     Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
        at czt.c(:com.google.android.gms@18382007@18.3.82 (020304-260264002):1)
        at axhu.a(:com.google.android.gms@18382007@18.3.82 (020304-260264002):1)
        at axib.a(:com.google.android.gms@18382007@18.3.82 (020304-260264002):5)
        at axib.a(:com.google.android.gms@18382007@18.3.82 (020304-260264002):124)
        at aakf.a(:com.google.android.gms@18382007@18.3.82 (020304-260264002):1)
        at czv.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@18382007@18.3.82 (020304-260264002):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
        at aale.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@18382007@18.3.82 (020304-260264002):19)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
09-04 20:32:15.395 31728-31728/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
09-04 20:32:15.395 31728-31728/? E/Zygote: v2
09-04 20:32:15.405 31728-31728/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: untrusted sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-04 20:32:16.426 31755-31755/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
09-04 20:32:16.426 31755-31755/? E/Zygote: v2
09-04 20:32:16.436 31755-31755/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: untrusted sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-04 20:32:17.577 31728-31777/? E/GEL_DELAYED_EVENT_DEBUG: Failed delayed event dispatch, no dispatchers.
09-04 20:32:21.721 1633-27449/? E/NetworkScheduler.ATC: Received callback from client for task that is already complete. ComponentInfo{com.google.android.youtube/com.google.android.libraries.youtube.common.gcore.gcoreclient.gcm.impl.GcmTaskServiceDelegator} device_context_task
09-04 20:33:02.525 31881-31881/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
09-04 20:33:02.525 31881-31881/? E/Zygote: v2
09-04 20:33:02.535 31881-31881/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: untrusted sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-04 20:33:04.947 769-1052/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 2701 [09-04 20:33:04.956]
09-04 20:33:05.348 31755-31767/? E/SQLiteLog: (283) recovered 284 frames from WAL file /data/user/0/com.google.android.gsf/databases/googlesettings.db-wal
09-04 20:33:28.844 31964-31964/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
09-04 20:33:28.844 31964-31964/? E/Zygote: v2
09-04 20:33:28.854 31964-31964/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: platform sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-04 20:33:29.164 769-855/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=631, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
09-04 20:33:29.484 31982-31982/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
09-04 20:33:29.484 31982-31982/? E/Zygote: v2
09-04 20:33:29.484 31982-31982/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: platform sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-04 20:34:04.375 31881-31924/? E/Finsky: [39226] guw.a(24): Unable to build selector: /storage/emulated/0/Download/marketenvs.csv: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-04 20:34:05.456 32014-32014/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
09-04 20:34:05.456 32014-32014/? E/Zygote: v2
09-04 20:34:05.456 32014-32014/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: untrusted sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-04 20:34:05.756 32014-32022/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
09-04 20:34:09.640 32033-32033/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
09-04 20:34:09.640 32033-32033/? E/Zygote: v2
09-04 20:34:09.640 32033-32033/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: untrusted sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-04 20:34:09.930 32048-32048/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
09-04 20:34:09.930 32048-32048/? E/Zygote: v2
09-04 20:34:09.930 32048-32048/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: platform sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-04 20:34:10.250 185-185/? E/refnotify: open /sys/class/graphics/fb0/dynamic_mipi_clk failed, error: No such file or directory
09-04 20:34:10.260 769-32068/? E/MISC PowerHAL: sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/event2/device/enabled: No such file or directory
09-04 20:34:10.330 32069-32069/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
09-04 20:34:10.330 32069-32069/? E/Zygote: v2
09-04 20:34:10.350 32069-32069/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-04 20:34:10.500 769-830/? E/MotionRecognitionService:  handler : SCREEN_ON end
09-04 20:34:10.611 769-898/? E/lights: write_int failed to open -1
09-04 20:34:10.631 769-793/? E/GpsLocationProvider: sExerciseInterface is not available
09-04 20:34:10.771 769-853/? E/WifiNative-wlan0: do suspend false
09-04 20:34:12.102 769-898/? E/lights: write_int failed to open -1
09-04 20:34:12.542 32069-32108/? E/SQLiteLog: (284) automatic index on clids(application)
09-04 20:34:13.363 32133-32133/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
09-04 20:34:13.363 32133-32133/? E/Zygote: v2
09-04 20:34:13.373 32133-32133/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: platform sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-04 20:34:13.423 769-855/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=632, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
09-04 20:34:13.613 32155-32155/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
09-04 20:34:13.613 32155-32155/? E/Zygote: v2
09-04 20:34:13.613 32155-32155/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: platform sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-04 20:34:13.714 32155-32155/? E/MTPRx: In MtpReceiverandroid.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE
09-04 20:34:13.724 32155-32155/? E/MTPRx: check value of boot_completed is1
09-04 20:34:13.724 32155-32155/? E/MTPRx: check booting is completed_sys.boot_completed
09-04 20:34:13.734 32155-32155/? E/MTPRx: Sd-Card path/storage/extSdCard
09-04 20:34:13.734 32155-32155/? E/MTPRx: Status for mount/Unmount :mounted
09-04 20:34:13.734 32155-32155/? E/MTPRx: SDcard is  available
09-04 20:34:13.744 32155-32155/? E/MTPRx: Received USB_STATE with sdCardLaunch = 0
09-04 20:34:13.744 32155-32155/? E/MTPRx: mFirstTime: false
09-04 20:34:13.804 32155-32155/? E/MTPJNIInterface: Getting CryptionKey from JAVA
09-04 20:34:13.804 32155-32155/? E/MTPRx: currentUserId is 0
09-04 20:34:13.814 32155-32155/? E/MTPRx: mtpCurrentGlobalUserId is 0
09-04 20:34:13.834 32155-32155/? E/MTPRx: Start observing USB_STATE_MATCH 
09-04 20:34:13.834 32155-32155/? E/MTPRx: cannot open file : /sys/class/android_usb/android0/bcdUSB
09-04 20:34:13.834 32155-32155/? E/MTPRx: is_Privatemode is NOT 1
09-04 20:34:13.844 32155-32155/? E/MTPJNIInterface: noti = 12
09-04 20:34:13.864 32155-32155/? E/MTPRx: Setting the status to phone Lock
```

Может ли причина заключаться в нехватке памяти на телефоне(всего 500мб свободного места)?

Comment: На главной панели какие предлагаются устройства?

Comment: Invalidate cache and restart пробовали?

Comment: попробуй сбросить кэш, перестроить проект,запусти,  посмотри лог на ошибки

Comment: @IvanVovk да, не помогло

Comment: @Style-7 только мой телефон, больше ничего.

Comment: @Leshka в логах куча ошибок, с которыми я не встречался раньше

Comment: а вы раньше работали с этим телефоном? в настройках разработчика разрешена установка через USB?

Comment: @Style-7 постоянно работаю, установка через USB включена

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче, ребят, после двух дней бесполезного поиска решил проверить /tmp(вдруг решение проблемы кроется именно там). Проверил опции /tmp и увидел noexec. попробовал mount -o remount,exec /tmp, заtем перезагрузил студию и все заработало как надо.